# Best way to remember users using google wallet for digital goods

Tags: php, android-pay

I am trying to implement Google wallet for digital goods inside an app to get users more advanced features.
So far i need to identify the user and their purchase for their next log in(That way they get extra features added automatically on their next login). So far the json looks  like this one below from Google wallet purchase.
Anyone done this before? I am trying to stay away from having the users use a custom sign up form. Any help would be great on how to best implement this.

```
$payload = array(
"iss" => $sellerIdentifier,
"aud" => "Google",
"typ" => "google/payments/inapp/item/v1",
"exp" => time() + 3600,
"iat" => time(),
"request" => array (
"name" => "Piece of Cake",
"description" => "Virtual chocolate cake to fill your virtual tummy"
"price" => "10.50",
"currencyCode" => "USD",
"sellerData" => "user_id:1224245,offer_code:3098576987,affiliate:aksdfbovu9j",
)
);
$cakeToken = JWT::encode($payload, $sellerSecret);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought - look into [Google Plus sign in](https://developers.google.com/+/) and see if that meets your requirements. I've sort of toyed with it [here](http://code.edchavez.com/iap-dotnet) though it's a bit "hacky" being a demo page :)

The idea is that Google Wallet == Google Account, so "keeping it within Google" seems path of least resistance. You can see where it could be used in the `sellerData` field in the JWT...

Again, I haven't gone too far with it and you'll have to determine if the (user) info you get is "enough" for your SSO needs....

Hth and happy holidays!

Comment: I will look into the Google plus sign in. A client sign in id would actually be enough for what i want to do.